# Замена текста

Tags: preg_match, php, mysql

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу реализовать правильно замену.
В общем, ситуация такая: из базы выводится сообщение, в котором может присутствовать текст вида `@123`, где `123` - номер ид человека из базы . Необходимо заменять текст такого вида в ссылку, где цифры после знака собаки и есть id человека, так же в ссылке должен быть только ид человека.

Вот как я сделал:

```
<? print preg_replace('/@(\d+)/',   '<a href="/здесь должен быть id без знака собаки">Здесь тоже только id человека</a>',  $c['msg']); ?>
```

Не подскажете, как можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
<? print preg_replace('/@(\d+)/',   '<a href="/$1">$1</a>',  $c['msg']); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Оказывается, все сложное - просто. =)

Comment: Правильно поставленный вопрос содержит половину ответа :-)